# Thymeleaf: how to pass main.js to require.js via data-main

Tags: javascript, requirejs, thymeleaf

We have a project where we want to use `require.js` along with our uncompressed main app.js in developer environments, so we have tried this script declaration in our main Thymeleaf template html:

```
<script
    th:if="${@applicationProperties.getStage() == 'dev'}"
    th:src="@{'/js/shared/lib/amd/require.min.js'}"
    data-main="@{'/js/app.js'}">
</script>
```

Watching the network traffic in the browser shows, that loading the require.min.js works, so Thymeleaf prepends the context in the th:src.

Also the app.js obviously is passed to require since you can see that the browser is trying to load whatever you pass to require via data-main.

However, using @{} to prepend the context to `"/js/app.js"` results in something like `http://localhost:7000/myapp/@%7B'/js/app.js'%7D.js`. So I assume Thymeleaf is not processing the value of the data-main tag.

Using `data:main` from Thymeleaf does not work at all.

If we hard code the context path, then everything is fine:

```
data-main="/myapp/js/app.js">
```

So, how can we prepend the context path to the script location?

Comment: Ok, just fixed it:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:if="${@applicationProperties.getStage() == 'dev'}"
    th:src="@{'/js/shared/lib/amd/require.min.js'}"
    th:attr="data-main=@{/js/app.js}">
</script>
```

Note, that there are no apostrophes in the value of th:attr!

Comment: Or you could use HTML5 data attributes: `data-th-attr="data-main=@{/js/app.js}"`